# Trim character from String

Tags: c#

I want to remove separater from Date

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
```

returns `mm/dd/yyyy` as `4/13/2012`. then how  can i remove `'/'` from the string.

I am converting date string to int32 as:

```
Convert.ToInt32(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Trim(new char[]{'/'}));
```

but trim does not trim the character between the string.

Any another better suggestion to do this will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the desired result is `4132012`?

Comment: try using replace with `String.Empty` or `replace("/","")`

Comment: Trim removes all LEADING and TRAILING occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object. To remove other one's use Replace method.

Comment: Do you want an Mdyyyy format integer or a ToShortDateString without the DateSeparator?

Comment: yes i want ToShortDateString out dateseparator.. i will go with the `Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
string dateSeparator = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator; 

Convert.ToInt32(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace(dateSeparator, ""));
```

**Edit: As per @Tim comment**
    Another way is use the [DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

```
Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
```

Comment: This will result in a `FormatException` for me since my culture uses points as separator("de-DE").

Answer (score 2):

```
string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
string str = date.Replace("/", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Cannot be converted to an int. At least in different cultures than "en-US" which uses other separators like points(f.e. "de-DE").

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the desired result:

```
String result = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mddyyyy");  //"4132012"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var dateSep= Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator;
var date= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace(dateSep,"");
int intdate=int.Parse(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing the `/` separator, you can just format that date directly:

`Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy"));`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just generate the string in the target format:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy")
```